# Changing grid line colours in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to change the grid line (and border) colours of a graph I'm using. I've seen the docs, but only found methods to change the `fill`. Can't see anything regarding the actual lines.

**Demo**:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
    "xValue": "Q1",
    "yValue": 3
}, {
    "xValue": "Q2",
    "yValue": 4
}, {
    "xValue": "Q3",
    "yValue": 7
}, {
    "xValue": "Q4",
    "yValue": 2
}, {
    "xValue": "Q5",
    "yValue": 9
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";
theXAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";
series1.fill = "#2c3e96";
series1.fillOpacity = .3;
series1.stroke = "#4967fa";

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
body{
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```

By the lines I'm referring to those dark grey grid lines.

Any way to change this?

Answer (score 6):

In the [axis renderer](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/axisrenderer/), you have access to many components of the axis, such as labels, ticks, and , including the [grid lines](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/axisrenderer/#grid_property). You can change the grid line colors by modifying the grid template.

```
theXAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";
theYAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";
```

This is also demonstrated in the axis overview in the documentation under the [Grid, labels and ticks section](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Grid_labels_and_ticks).

As for the border, you need to set the stroke on the relevant container's background (in this case, the plotContainer). You can find more information on working with containers [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/svg-engine/containers/#Styling_containers)

```
chart.plotContainer.background.stroke = "#ff0000";
```

```js
var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
    "xValue": "Q1",
    "yValue": 3
}, {
    "xValue": "Q2",
    "yValue": 4
}, {
    "xValue": "Q3",
    "yValue": 7
}, {
    "xValue": "Q4",
    "yValue": 2
}, {
    "xValue": "Q5",
    "yValue": 9
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";
theXAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
theXAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";
theXAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 2; 
theXAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = .8; //make the change more visible for demo purposes
// base/zero line
theXAxis.renderer.baseGrid.stroke = "#ff0000";

/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
theYAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";
theYAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 2; 
theYAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = .8; //make the change more visible for demo purposes
// base/zero line
theYAxis.renderer.baseGrid.stroke = "#ff0000";

//border around chart:
chart.plotContainer.background.stroke = "#ff0000";


/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";
series1.fill = "#2c3e96";
series1.fillOpacity = .3;
series1.stroke = "#4967fa";

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
body{
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```